# Why doesn't this timer work for actionListener?

Tags: java

I want to create a program where each second it prints "tick" to the console.
I want to do this using the ActionListener interface. I created a timer object with a delay of 1000 milli-seconds.

This approach with ActionListener and Timer worked in other projects, but it doesn't here.

I will appreciate it if someone could help me.

```
package mainPackage;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Game extends Canvas implements ActionListener {
    
    Timer timer;
    
    public Game() {
        timer = new Timer(1000, this);
        timer.start();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Tick");
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Game();
    }

}
```

I am new to java, so I am sorry if this is a stupid question!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try displaying a swing component. Your program should continue, and the timer run, while the component is visible. Or try using util Timer instead of a swing Timer.

Comment: This seems to have fixed the problem for me! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume the problem is that your program is finishing immediately. The swing Timer does not prevent your program from ending. Try displaying a swing component. Your program should continue, and the timer run, while the component is visible.

Alternatively you could use [`java.util.Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) instead of `javax.swing.Timer`. The util Timer can create [non-deamon threads](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon-boolean-), which should keep your program alive.